# Orientacion pantalla cambios Android

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

El problema es que tengo un `Spinner` abierto y cuando paso de la orientación vertical a la horizontal se me cierra y al pasar de la orientación horizontal a la vertical no.

He puesto esto en el `Android Manifest`:

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
```

Comment: Estas seguro que deseas usar todas las propiedades, son necesarias para tu Activity?  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element

Answer (score 0):

No debes usar todas las [propiedades de android:configChanges](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element), creo que con las siguientes es suficiente:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

esta es su descripción:

- "keyboardHidden"  Cambió la accesibilidad del teclado; por ejemplo, el usuario expuso el teclado de hardware.
- "orientation" Cambió la orientación de la pantalla; el usuario giró el dispositivo.
- "screenSize"  Cambió el tamaño de la pantalla actualmente disponible.
  Representa un cambio en el tamaño actualmente disponible en función de la relación de aspecto actual. Por lo tanto, variará cuando el usuario alterne la orientación vertical y la horizontal.